Splitting raw telemetry data into parts
Completely new to ThingsBoard (TB), and quite new to integrations in general, so be gentle. Have though successfully used Losant to display air quality related data.
Data sent from the device consists of a simple string with 8 floats, e.g. "22.38, 34.73, 66.00, 1.00, 3.00, 3.30, 3.40, 3.40".
I'm able to display this string as such in TB, but how to split it to the different components (community edition)?
Telemetry data
I suppose I should use Rule Chains, have tried that, but am not able to get the output to be in the form I believe it should be in, i.e.
{
"temp": 23.5,
"humi": 33.1,
"voci": 11,
"noxi": 23,
"pm10": 33,
"pm25": 55,
"pm40": 55,
"pm100": 99
}
Instead I get this:
{
"msg": {
"payload": "22.38, 34.73, 66.00, 1.00, 3.00, 3.30, 3.40, 3.40"
},
"metadata": {
"deviceType": "default",
"deviceName": "Test Device",
"ts": "1734519560226"
},
"msgType": "POST_TELEMETRY_REQUEST"
}
Went through other similar questions, but those cases seem to be using keys and values instead of raw values.
Script transform node

You are returning wrong data format for script node (https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/transformation-nodes/#script-transformation-node).
You should get 8 different telemetries by using following script:
// Extract the payload string
var parts = msg.payload.split(",");

// Map the values to telemetry keys
var telemetry = {
    temp: parseFloat(parts[0].trim()),
    humi: parseFloat(parts[1].trim()),
    voci: parseFloat(parts[2].trim()),
    noxi: parseFloat(parts[3].trim()),
    pm10: parseFloat(parts[4].trim()),
    pm25: parseFloat(parts[5].trim()),
    pm40: parseFloat(parts[6].trim()),
    pm100: parseFloat(parts[7].trim())
};

// Return the formatted telemetry
return { msg: telemetry, metadata: metadata, msgType: msgType };



Thank you very much, this worked!
